# How to count conditional formatting based on colour by name and name is given by another column in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

How to count conditional formatting based on colour by name and name is given by another column in google sheets like this.

[image]

Comment: I'm using script count color but by name still pending

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Conditional format colors are stored as the cell background.  Also colors are stored as hex representation, not by color names.  However there is a table of colors used by Google Spreadsheet with the hex and color names.  I've used the sample conditional formats shown below to demonstrate.

[image]

**Script**

```
function countColors() {
  try {

    let colors = [["#000000", "black"],                   ["#434343", "dark gray 4"],
                  ["#666666", "dark gray 3"],             ["#999999", "dark gray 2"],
                  ["#b7b7b7", "dark gray 1"],             ["#cccccc", "gray"],
                  ["#d9d9d9", "light gray 1"],            ["#efefef", "light gray 2"],
                  ["#f3f3f3", "light gray 3"],            ["#ffffff", "white"],
                  ["#980000", "red berry"],               ["#ff0000", "red"],
                  ["#ff9900", "orange"],                  ["#ffff00", "yellow"],
                  ["#00ff00", "green"],                   ["#00ffff", "cyan"],
                  ["#4a86e8", "cornflower blue"],         ["#0000ff", "blue"],
                  ["#9900ff", "purple"],                  ["#ff00ff", "magenta"],
                  ["#e6b8af", "light red berry 3"],       ["#f4cccc", "light red 3"],
                  ["#fce5cd", "light orange 3"],          ["#fff2cc", "light yellow 3"],
                  ["#d9ead3", "light green 3"],           ["#d0e0e3", "light cyan 3"],
                  ["#c9daf8", "light cornflower blue 3"], ["#cfe2f3", "light blue 3"],
                  ["#d9d2e9", "light purple 3"],          ["#ead1dc", "light magenta 3"],
                  ["#dd7e6b", "light red berry 2"],       ["#ea9999", "light red 2"],
                  ["#f9cb9c", "light orange 2"],          ["#ffe599", "light yellow 2"],
                  ["#b6d7a8", "light green 2"],           ["#a2c4c9", "light cyan 2"],
                  ["#a4c2f4", "light cornflower blue 2"], ["#9fc5e8", "light blue 2"],
                  ["#b4a7d6", "light purple 2"],          ["#d5a6bd", "light magenta 2"],
                  ["#cc4125", "light red berry 1"],       ["#e06666", "light red 1"],
                  ["#f6b26b", "light orange 1"],          ["#ffd966", "light yellow 1"],
                  ["#93c47d", "light green 1"],           ["#76a5af", "light cyan 1"],
                  ["#6d9eeb", "light cornflower blue 1"], ["#6fa8dc", "light blue 1"],
                  ["#8e7cc3", "light purple 1"],          ["#c27ba0", "light magenta 1"],
                  ["#a61c00", "dark red berry 1"],        ["#cc0000", "dark red 1"],
                  ["#e69138", "dark orange 1"],           ["#f1c232", "dark yellow 1"],
                  ["#6aa84f", "dark green 1"],            ["#45818e", "dark cyan 1"],
                  ["#3c78d8", "dark cornflower blue 1"],  ["#3d85c6", "dark blue 1"],
                  ["#674ea7", "dark purple 1"],           ["#a64d79", "dark magenta 1"],
                  ["#85200c", "dark red berry 2"],        ["#990000", "dark red 2"],
                  ["#b45f06", "dark orange 2"],           ["#bf9000", "dark yellow 2"],
                  ["#38761d", "dark green 2"],            ["#134f5c", "dark cyan 2"],
                  ["#1155cc", "dark cornflower blue 2"],  ["#0b5394", "dark blue 2"],
                  ["#351c75", "dark purple 2"],           ["#741b47", "dark magenta 2"],
                  ["#5b0f00", "dark red berry 3"],        ["#660000", "dark red 3"],
                  ["#783f04", "dark orange 3"],           ["#7f6000", "dark yellow 3"],
                  ["#274e13", "dark green 3"],            ["#0c343d", "dark cyan 3"],
                  ["#1c4587", "dark cornflower blue 3"],  ["#073763", "dark blue 3"],
                  ["#20124d", "dark purple 3"],           ["#4c1130", "dark magenta 3"]]; 
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName("MultiSelect");
    let backgrounds = sh.getRange("E1:E17").getBackgrounds();
    let unique = [...new Set(backgrounds.flat())];
    let counts = unique.map( backgrounds => 0 );
    console.log(counts);
    backgrounds.forEach( background => { let i = unique.indexOf(background[0]);
                                counts[i] = counts[i]+1; });
    for( let i=0; i<unique.length; i++ ) {
      let color = colors.find( color => color[0] === unique[i] );
      console.log("color = "+color[1]+" count = "+counts[i]);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

6:31:56 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:31:57 AM  Info    [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
6:31:57 AM  Info    color = white count = 8
6:31:57 AM  Info    color = orange count = 5
6:31:57 AM  Info    color = yellow count = 2
6:31:57 AM  Info    color = magenta count = 2
6:31:57 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getBackgrounds()
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp
- https://spreadsheet.dev/how-to-get-the-hexadecimal-codes-of-colors-in-google-sheets